# How do I display the flushbar notification of my app even if it is closed

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using flushbar to display some important in-app notifications of my App to the user.

I want to be able to display the flushbar that is independent of the app open or closed.Because the flushbar notification is drawn over the current BuildContext only, as soon as the user closes the App , the flushbar notification disappears as well (because the notification widget is part of that screen's widget subtree).

Is there a way to display the flushbar notification on top of the other apps,in spite of my App being closed??

This is the Flushbar code I want to display.

In other words is there any kind of stuff where in which we can run a function or a piece of dart code irrespective of the app being closed or open?

I have been breaking my head for this for the past 5 days and I am not getting it

```
Flushbar(
          title: "Hey",
          message: "This is the important message XYZ for you.",
          duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
          isDismissible: true,

          icon: Icon(
            Icons.warning,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          dismissDirection: FlushbarDismissDirection
              .HORIZONTAL,


          mainButton: FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              flush.dismiss(true);
            },
            child: Text(
              "CANCEL",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber),
            ),
          ),
```

)

Comment: If you are on android, I think you can go to native code and create a background service and run your function there,but even in this case I doubt that you can show any dialogs or toasts if your app is not in foreground

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin [system_alert_window](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/system_alert_window)

> A flutter plugin to show Truecaller like overlay window, over all other apps along with callback events.

Using that, Build your notification which will act like a floating window on top of all apps and more importantly, it runs in the background.